# How to suppress web.py output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, stderr, web.py

I am trying to suppress the `web.py` output from the console. I do not wish to suppress all output to stderr or redirect the output, but merely stop it from printing statements such as the following to the console.

```
127.0.0.1:57691 - - [06/Mar/2018 22:25:43] "HTTP/1.1 GET /api/getDimensionColumnConstraints" - 200 OK
```

I have tried adding the `web.config.debug = False` statement as the first line in my `main()` function and it still prints this for every API call.

Comment: If you don't want to redirect the output where do you expect it to go?

Comment: This might help: http://webpy.org/cookbook/logging

Comment: logging.captureWarnings(True)

Comment: @I'L'I I don't want there to be an output in the first place. I have a feeling this is not possible though and so my only option is to redirect it.

Comment: I want to do the opposite! It gives me no output regarding error messages and am trying to get it to give me some..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in server for web.py sends the HTTP info and other errors to stderr by default. I'm with you -- I want the errors, but don't want all the HTTP statements.

So, here's what you can do.

1. Create a custom Logger
2. Intercept calls within the logger, tossing out log records matching the pattern.

Not so hard, you'll create a basic wsgi application middleware to intercept:

```
import logging
class Log:
    def __init__(self, xapp, logname="wsgi"):
        class O:
            def __init__(self, xapp, logname="wsgi"):
                self.logger = logging.getLogger(logname)
            def write(self, s):
                if s[-1] == '\n':
                    s = s[:-1]
                if s == "":
                    return
                if self.ignore(s):
                    return
                self.logger.debug(s)
        self.app = xapp
        self.f = O(logname)
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['wsgi.errors'] = self.f
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Add that middleware into your `__main__` initialization of the application. You probably have something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Change the `run()` to add the middleware:

```
    app.run(Log)
```

Now the second part. See the `self.ignore(s)` within  O.write() above? Use that to decide to process or ignore the logging statement, for example I do:

```
def ignore(self, s):
    if not all([web.config.get('debug_http', False),
               any(['"HTTP/1.1 GET ' in s,
                    '"HTTP/1.1 POST ' in s])]):
        return True
    return False
```

Which basically says if the string to print contains 'HTTP...' ignore it. I've added the check to a global flag 'debug_http', which allows me to set that (somewhere, anywhere, anyhow) to enable / disable this item.